# Maven Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Hi I am following this tutorial: http://www.mastertheboss.com/hibernate/182-hibernate-tutorial.html

I have done all the code so I add this run configuration:
package -e -DgroupId=it.michelepierri -DartifactId=FirstExampleHibernate

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.michele</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstExampleHibernate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FirstExampleHibernate</name>
<description>Primo esempio di utilizzo Hibernate</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core<!--or hibernate-core--></artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <!--hibernate-dependencies is a pom, not needed for hibernate-core -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>it.michele.TestPerson</mainClass>
                        <packageName>it.michele</packageName>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So I run it and console says me:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ FirstExampleHibernate ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Michele\workspace\FirstExampleHibernate\target\FirstExampleHibernate-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.707s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 11 14:59:50 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I try to launch the jar I have returned:

```
C:\Users\Michele\workspace\FirstExampleHibernate\target>java -jar 

FirstExampleHibernate-0.0.1-SNAPSH
OT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: it.michelepierri.TestPerson. Program will exit.
```

What I am doing wrong??????
In TestPerson.java class there is public static void main(String[] args) method.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to run the jar with a classpath that includes your dependencies.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: You might want to use the current releases of hibernate (Hibernate 3.3 was released in 2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering the problem because all the supporting jars (hibernate etc) are not specified in the classpath.

Try

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=it.michelepierri.TestPerson
```

This is a maven command that will internally invoke java with all the dependent jars added to the classpath.

You can also try

```
mvn assembly:single
```

which will combine all the jars into one which you then use the run it the way you are doing now.

Comment: The first command return me:[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project FirstExampleHibernate: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: It is `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=it.michelepierri.TestPerson`